# Get last elements of array having same ID

Tags: javascript, arrays

Get the last values from the array having same ids:

Input:

```
[{id:1,name:"Java"},{id:1,name:"JavaScript"},{id:1,name:"Python"},{id:1,name:"C++"},{id:2,name:"C"},{id:2,name:"Ruby"},{id:2,name:"Php"}]
```

Required Output:

```
[{id:1,name:"C++"},{id:2,name:"Php"}]
```

So, I have tried doing

```
array?.reverse().filter( (ele, ind) => ind === array.findIndex((elem) => elem?.id === ele?.id))
```

but it gives me the output `[{id:1,name:"Java"},{id:2,name:"C"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a straightforward `Array.reduce()` for this purpose, creating a map keyed on `id`. We'll use `Object.values()` to turn our map into an array:

```js
const input = [{id:1,name:"Java"},{id:1,name:"JavaScript"},{id:1,name:"Python"},{id:1,name:"C++"},{id:2,name:"C"},{id:2,name:"Ruby"},{id:2,name:"Php"}];

const result = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
    acc[cur.id] = cur;
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result)
```

One could also use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) and `reduce` again:

```js
const input = [{id:1,name:"Java"},{id:1,name:"JavaScript"},{id:1,name:"Python"},{id:1,name:"C++"},{id:2,name:"C"},{id:2,name:"Ruby"},{id:2,name:"Php"}];
const result = [...input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return acc.set(cur.id, cur);
}, new Map()).values()];
console.log('Result:', result);
```